# Certain key event combinations not firing

Tags: java, key-bindings

While creating a simple bullet hell game, I encountered a problem with key bindings.

I'll give some background information on the mechanics of the game relating to key bindings. In this 2-dimensional game, your character can move in all eight directions at a constant speed by holding down non-numpad arrow-key combinations (up, left, and down+right for the directions North, East, and Southwest, respectively.) You can also hold down the shift key in combination with any of the previously mentioned key combinations to move in the same directions, but at a slower constant speed.

Here is the code for an example of a program encountering this issue. The issue is the same in this example as it is in the comparatively large bullet hell program.

```
/*
 * Keybind feedback, by Nematodes
 */

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class keybindFeedback extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
    JPanel framePanel = new JPanel();
    private static Action moveUpTrue;
    private static Action moveUpFalse;
    private static Action moveUpFocusedTrue;
    private static Action moveUpFocusedFalse;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        keybindFeedback createFrame = new keybindFeedback();
        createFrame.constructFrame();
    }

    public void constructFrame()
    {
        // Construct the frame and frame components
        setTitle("Keybind Feedback");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setVisible(true);

        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints;

        // This JPanel only exists so that it is easier to focus on the window, so that keyevents will register
        gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
        framePanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        framePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
        getContentPane().add(framePanel, gridConstraints);

        pack();

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((int) (0.5 * (screenSize.width - getWidth())),
                 (int) (0.5 * (screenSize.height - getHeight())), getWidth(), getHeight());

        // Initialize and map all of the keybinds
        moveUpTrue = new MoveUpTrue();
        moveUpFalse = new MoveUpFalse();
        moveUpFocusedTrue = new MoveUpFocusedTrue();
        moveUpFocusedFalse = new MoveUpFocusedFalse();

        // Code spacing for placing things in the input map is only wonky in this code-formatting block due to strange spacing issues in stackoverflow
        framePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "doMoveUpTrue");

        framePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released UP"), "doMoveUpFalse");
        framePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift UP"), "doMoveUpFocusedTrue");

        framePanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift released UP"), "doMoveUpFocusedFalse");

        framePanel.getActionMap().put("doMoveUpTrue", moveUpTrue);
        framePanel.getActionMap().put("doMoveUpFalse", moveUpFalse);
        framePanel.getActionMap().put("doMoveUpFocusedTrue", moveUpFocusedTrue);
        framePanel.getActionMap().put("doMoveUpFocusedFalse", moveUpFocusedFalse);
    }

    // Keybind actions for up, up released, shift-up, and shift-up released
    class MoveUpTrue extends AbstractAction
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Up");
        }
    }

    class MoveUpFalse extends AbstractAction
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Up released");
        }
    }

    class MoveUpFocusedTrue extends AbstractAction
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Shift-up");
        }
    }

    class MoveUpFocusedFalse extends AbstractAction
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Shift-up released");
        }
    }
}
```

If you press up for a couple seconds and then release it, the program will fire lots of up pressed events, and then an up released event. In-game, this would be moving up at a standard speed.

If you press shift, then press up for a couple of seconds, then release up, the program will fire lots of shift-up pressed events, and then a shift-up released event. Shift must be pressed first, and released last (if you release it at all) for this to work. In-game, this would be moving up at a slower speed.

If you press shift, then press up for a couple of seconds, then release shift, then release up a couple of seconds after releasing shift, the program will first fire lots of shift-up pressed events, then fire up pressed events, and finally fire an up released event. In-game, this would be moving up at a slower speed, then deciding to move up at a faster speed.

If you press up for a couple of seconds, then press shift, the program will first fire lots of up pressed events, then fire no events when shift is held-down. The expected behavior is that once shift it pressed while pressing up, it should start firing shift-up pressed events instead of up pressed events. This would be applicable in-game if the player was moving up at the standard speed, and then wanted to move at a slower speed.
Continuing from this previous scenario:
If you release shift while still pressing up, it will not fire any up pressed events despite you now only pressing up. If you release up now, it will still fire an up released event even when it never would fire any up pressed events.
If you release up while still holding shift, it will fire a shift-up released event, even when it never would fire any shift-up pressed events.

This is not an issue with key rollover on my keyboard, as it can press all of these keys in combination alright.
This isn't an issue with java not accepting key events either.
This is natural Windows 7 (the OS I am using) behavior, that happens to be problematic. The same behavior will be seen when using shift and letter keys in a normal text box.

Now to ask, is there a way to circumvent the operating system's key event handling so that pressing shift while holding up will trigger shift-up pressed events?

Comment: Based on my limited testing, unless the shift key is pressed before the up key, the `shift+up` binding will no be triggered...

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).